# bad autoincrementation when copying tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have two tables in my databaes: original_db and archive_db.

in original_db I have  two cols:

1. id (auto-increment)
2. name

in archive_db I have three cols:

1. id (auto-increment)
2. user_id
3. name

I want to copy original_db to archive_db when user_id is let's say '1'

sql query:

```
INSERT INTO archive_db (user_id, name)
SELECT '1', name FROM original_db
```

After query this at first time everything is ok. So I Have archive_db:

1. id (auto-increment) [1,2,3]
2. user_id [1,1,1]
3. name [nam1,name2,name3]

but when I do again this query with another user_id let's say '2':

```
    INSERT INTO archive_db (user_id, name)
    SELECT '2', name FROM original_db
```

I get this archive_db table:

1. id (auto-increment) [1, 2, 3, **7, 8, 9**]
2. user_id [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
3. name [name1, name2, name3, name1, name2, name3]

Why the id has the wrong autoincrementation, it should be 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Its really helpful if you dont name tables with the word database or db. Databases hold tables and tables hold rows.

Comment: A variety of things could cause this to happen, such as an abandoned transaction or some internal optimization of some kind.  There's no guarantee that auto-increment values will always be sequential with no gaps.  It's merely guaranteed to be unique and always a larger number than previously inserted records.  It's not really a problem, it's just a behavior of that functionality.  (I bet there's a duplicate question which explains this in depth, I just haven't found it.)

Comment: Your select query is not limited to one row it is getting ALL the current rows in the table, this one `SELECT '1', name FROM original_db` and this one `SELECT '2', name FROM original_db` you would need to add a WHERE clause like `SELECT id, name FROM original_db WHERE id = 1`

Comment: What table types and AUTO_INCREMENT Lock Modes are you using? see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

And didn't 3 rows be deleted during the test? Then just set autoincrement: `ALTER TABLE archive_db AUTO_INCREMENT = 4;`